# Cannot resolve symbol 'WRITE_SMS

Tags: android

Good day,

I'm just wondering why I can't call this permission `WRITE_SMS` in runtime. My project needs to ask the user to grant this permission but I can't even use this syntax `Manifest.permission.WRITE_SMS` in runtime.

For more clarification please take a look at the following codes below.

In my Manifest.xml file, I just declared these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

and to ask the user during runtime, I'm using this code

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
        };
        
        new RxPermissions(this)
                .request(PERMISSIONS)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (granted) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "All permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Some permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

as you can see, I didn't include the `WRITE_SMS` in my code because when I include that permission it will turn like this

[image]

I'm just wondering, I can use these permissions `READ_SMS` and `SEND_SMS` both in Manifest.xml file and in during runtime but not this permission `WRITE_SMS`. My project keeps rejected 6 times by google because of the `"violation of Permissions policy"` so I'm hoping that my project will be granted if I can request this permission (WRITE_SMS) during runtime.

Comment: `android.permission.WRITE_SMS`

Comment: It doesn't work either.  this `android.permission.WRITE_SMS` works only in Manifest.xml file but not inside the java class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into Manifest.permission class you'd notice that WRITE_SMS permission is no longer there. I might be wrong but I think it has been removed by Google from API 23. 
And if I'm not mistaken Google now may not allow to publish your app in the store if you want to use read/write SMS in your app regardless of the permissions you ask.

Comment: This answer's correct - only particular apps can use this permission (I believe only if set as the system default SMS app).

Comment: My app is all about sending and receiving SMS because it's a text voting app. If it that's true that they no longer allowed us to use that permission so my project doesn't really have a chance to publish it to the play store. So sad. :-(

Comment: If I reduce my targetSdkVersion to the maximum allowed by google do you think my app has a chance to publish it to the play store?